# Moving points based on updated x,y values

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

In an ArcGIS Pro project, I have a feature class with over 2,000 points and I have updated the x,y fields of about 100 of these using a script. I now need the locations of these points on the map to move to reflect their new coordinates. I do not want to create a new feature class. I just want to update the locations of the points within this one.

Is there a script I can run to do this?

I do not want to manually move 100 points

Comment: Could you please share what you have already tried?

Comment: Select your updated points and calculate Shape field using arcpy.Point(!newx!,!newy!)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. My rule of thumb is to not bother saving scripts under 20 lines of code. This more like five lines,  and can be accomplished a number of ways including a DA UpdateCursor (the doc for which probably has a sample) and CalculateField. The most common comments here are "What have you tried?" and "Where are you stuck?". If your Question doesn't show any effort, it might get closed as lacking *detail*. Please [Edit] the Question.

Answer (score 2):

I'll guess that:

1. You have a way to select the points where the new coords are needed.
2. You have two columns with coords.

If thats the case do:

1. Filter the data
2. Get the coords, create Geometry
3. Make sure the Geometry is in the same spatial reference that you want it to be
4. Update the data

#this flux is with arcpy search cursor, do it if its a gdb,sde, if its a service or registered enterprise geodatabase in server you should do edits with ArcGIS API FeatureLayer,FeatureLayerCollection or using request.

```py
import arcpy
from arcgis.features import GeoAccessor
from arcgis.geometry import Geometry
import os
gdb_path = r"path.gdb"
feature_path=os.path.join(gdb_path,'mypoints')
point_sdf = GeoAccessor.from_featureclass(feature_path)
```

query your point with some column

```py
point_to_move_sdf = point_sdf.query("localpoints=='1'")
point_to_move_sdf
```

Do the update in the geometry

```py
for index, row in point_to_move_sdf.iterrows():
    objectid = row['OBJECTID']
    spatialReference = point_to_move_sdf.spatial.sr #data sr
    shape = Geometry({'x':row['LONG'], 'y':row['LAT'], 'spatialReference': {'wkid': 4326}}) ## Here the magic happens
    shape = shape.project_as(spatialReference).as_arcpy
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(feature_path, ['OBJECTID','SHAPE@'], where_clause=f'OBJECTID={objectid}') as cursor:
        for data in cursor:
            print(data)
            cursor.updateRow([objectid, shape])
```

Before
[image]
After
[image]

Comment: There is a one-line CalculateField option here, so using the ArcGIS Python API seems like the long way to solve this.